# Getting javax.resource.ResourceException when execting JPA query

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Getting javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction,when below code is exceuted

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select lower(name) FROM Attribute");
List temp= query.getResultList();
```

Exception is

```
17:15:27,838 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper]
(http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
17:15:27,841 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] 
(http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: 
Error checking for a transaction
17:15:27,845 ERROR [com.dao.impl.AttributeDaoImpl] 
(http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: 
Could not open connection
```

This exception is not frequent. I am not able to get the correct hint.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a `GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection` in the exception. Have you verified that you're not having connection or network issues?

Comment: In the same transactions we are executing other queries.it is not throwing any exception.only when executing JPA query "select lower(name) FROM Attribute"  it is throwing exception